# Tinymce 4.x insert flash player directly into the editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

I can't find any examples where I can insert a video player code into the tinymce 4.x, I'have a jwplayer downloaded, but I don't know how to insert the javascript code into the editor to execute this for each added video:

```
jwplayer(id).setup({
                    file: video.href,
                    image: video.img,
                    title: video.title,
                    width: '640',
                    height: '360',
                    primary: 'flash',
                    aspectratio: '16:9'
                });
```

please any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try initialising the player in the [onLoadContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onLoadContent) event handler of TinyMCE.

E.g.

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onLoadContent.add(function(ed, o) {
         jwplayer(id).setup({
            file: video.href,
            image: video.img,
            title: video.title,
            width: '640',
            height: '360',
            primary: 'flash',
            aspectratio: '16:9'
          });
      });
   }
});
```

The pont is that you need an element in user provided content to be available for DOM manipulation *before* setting up the player.

Comment: great, but this will work only for 1 video player that is already embeded? how should I execute it every time I add a new video block in the editor?

Comment: If you want do this every time a "video block" is inserted in the editor, use the onChange handler instead. Whatever way you add such a video block, you should be able to find them in the editor content when this handler executes. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange